# In Eureka Server, Discovey and Registration of Services/Applications NOT developed in Spring

Tags: java, go, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

How can web applications built without Spring (say, on Java-JEE and Go) be discovered and registered in Eureka Server ?

In a Spring-Boot application, it is easy to add these annotations:

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
```

before

```
public class EurekaClientApp{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaClientApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

and in configuration, application.properties

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
```

But for applications which were built not as Spring-Boot or for that matter as Microservices, how should they be discovered and registered as clients by Eureka Server

Answer (score 0):

It's like any other backend service; you have to use the right **client**. For example, if you have non-spring Java services, you could use;

```
InstanceInfo nextServerInfo = DiscoveryManager.getInstance()
                .getDiscoveryClient()
                .getNextServerFromEureka(vipAddress, false);

        Socket s = new Socket();
        int serverPort = nextServerInfo.getPort();
        try {
            s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(nextServerInfo.getHostName(),
                    serverPort));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not connect to the server :"
                    + nextServerInfo.getHostName() + " at port " + serverPort);
        }
```

https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Understanding-eureka-client-server-communication

Here's a Python client;

https://pypi.org/project/py-eureka-client/

A golang client;

https://github.com/hudl/fargo

Comment: Thanks Laksitha, let me try that.

Comment: Is not .getNextServerFromEureka(vipAddress, false); always picks from what is registered in Eureka Server ? In that case, how to register this 'on-spring Java service' in Eureka ?

Registering in Eureka is still not done.

Comment: I said non-spring & that’s Netflix documentation. You have to try out and get it working, look for any issues reported on github too. We’re not able to do thorough troubleshooting in stackoverflow.